# Is there some direct function in linux to retrieve the entire command line arguments in the application

Tags: command-line, bash

The command line arguments are received as the parameters in the int main function.

However, In windows there is also an alternative function GetCommandLineW() that retrieves the entire command line as a single string, which helps to get the arguments anytime later in the application without needing to store them.

Is there some similar method available in linux environment that can fetch the command line argument?

Comment: There is the external [`getopt`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/man1/getopt.1.html) and the Bash shell builtin [`getopts`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-getopts)

Comment: @Raffa I think that is the answer.

Comment: @Jos Probably, unless OP has something else in mind ... For example a more general shell special parameter context like `$@` or `$*` parsing ... or might even be not shell specific like in `C` which has a `getopt` with slightly different syntax ... Not clear yet, I think

Comment: True. I understand `GetCommandLineW()` is a C/C++ function, and the terms `int main function` also point to a C programming  issue. However, the question is tagged `command-line` and `bash`, which is slightly confusing.

Comment: @Jos Pardon for the tags. I m using a cpp application. And I was looking for any function or some file that stores the cmdline arguments. I dont want to store the argv in my program.

Comment: I don't understand *why* you would not use the `argv[]` array for this, however it should also be possible to obtain the information by reading the `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` pseudo file (after obtaining `<PID>` using the `getpid()` syscall for example). There are several Q&As about this on [so] e.g. [How can I get command line arguments passed to the running process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313640/how-can-i-get-command-line-arguments-passed-to-the-running-process)

Comment: I don't understand - ***you*** never have to store argv anywhere. The OS does that for you, that's it's job.

Answer (score 0):

The command line parameters are passed to

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

See https://computer.howstuffworks.com/c38.htm